# Creating HTML in python

Tags: python, html

I am looking for a way to create html files dynamically in python.  I am writing a gallery script, which iterates over directories, collecting file meta data.  I intended to then use this data to automatically create a picture gallery, based on html.  Something very simple, just a table of pictures.

I really don't think writing to a file manually is the best method, and the code may be very long.  So is there a better way to do this, possibly html specific?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think, if i understand you correctly, you can see [here, "Templating in Python"](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

Answer (score 91):

[Dominate](https://github.com/Knio/dominate) is a Python library for creating HTML documents and fragments directly in code without using templating. You could create a simple image gallery with something like this:

```py
import glob
from dominate import document
from dominate.tags import *

photos = glob.glob('photos/*.jpg')

with document(title='Photos') as doc:
    h1('Photos')
    for path in photos:
        div(img(src=path), _class='photo')


with open('gallery.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(doc.render())
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photos</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Photos</h1>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="photos/IMG_5115.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="photos/IMG_5117.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of dominate

Comment: Best thing since sliced bread. I have dabbled with the same ideas for 20 years, with false starts in **C**, Lisp and IIRC *(shudder)* PHP but my half-baked solutions were always even more painful than just sprinkling HTML between code (PHP) or `print`-ing HTML. The *Dominate* library just clicks for me. To me *Dominate* feels very lisp-y in the sense that you always hear that Lisp is great for using the *language itself* as a Domain Specific Language. Well, it turns out Python is really good for this as well!

Comment: Agreed! This is truly awsome

Comment: Well done, @Knio. Your library is still holding up after more than a decade. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 15):

Use a templating engine such as [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) or [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/).

Answer (score 10):

Python is a batteries included language. So why not use `xml.dom.minidom`?

```py
from typing import List
from xml.dom.minidom import getDOMImplementation, Document


def getDOM() -> Document:
    impl = getDOMImplementation()
    dt = impl.createDocumentType(
        "html",
        "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd",
    )
    return impl.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", dt)


def ul(items: List[str]) -> str:
    dom = getDOM()
    html = dom.documentElement
    ul = dom.createElement("ul")
    for item in items:
        li = dom.createElement("li")
        li.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(item))
        ul.appendChild(li)
    html.appendChild(ul)
    return dom.toxml()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(ul(["first item", "second item", "third item"]))
```

outputs:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html>
    <ul>
        <li>first item</li>
        <li>second item</li>
        <li>third item</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

The interface does not look like pythonic, but if you have been a fronted developer and used JavaScript DOM manipulation, it matches your mind better and yes it frees you from adding a needless dependency.

Comment: Very nice and simple example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Templating, as suggested in other answers, is probably the best answer (I wrote an early, quirky templating module called [yaptu](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52305/), but modern mature ones as suggested in other answers will probably make you happier;-).

However, though it's been a long time since I last used it, I fondly recall the [Quixote](http://www.mems-exchange.org/software/quixote/) approach, which is roughly a "reverse templating" (embedding HTML generation within Python, rather than viceversa as normal templating does).  Maybe you should take a look and see if you like it better;-).

Comment: I clicked around a little and it seems Quixote is still around. A description of for instance the button generator is here: http://quixote.ca/doc/widgets.txt   **.** All in all, it seems like you can put the Dominate library and Quixote in the same general category. But Quixote seems to do a lot of other things too, server related things. I like your term *"reverse templating"* - I will start using it to describe the general technique!

Answer (score 1):

Just write a file that contains html

```
a = '''
<html>
<head>
<h1> hello </h1>
</head>
</html>
  
'''
f = open("myhtmlfile.html", "a")
f.write(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Dominate is [Chope](https://github.com/hanstjua/chope), which also supports CSS.

Here's an example:

```py
from chope import *
from chope.css import *

page = html[
    head[
        style[
            Css[
                'body': dict(
                    background_color='linen',
                    font_size=pt/12
                ),
                '.inner-div': dict(
                    color='maroon',
                    margin_left=px/40
                )
            ]
        ]
    ],
    body[
        h1['Title'],
        div(class_='outer-div')[
            div(class_='inner-div')[
                'Some content.'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Which will give you

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: linen;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }
      
      .inner-div {
        color: maroon;
        margin-left: 40px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>
    <div class="outer-div">
      <div class="inner-div">
        Some content.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Disclaimer: I am the creator of Chope

Answer (score 0):

## Using ElementTree

You can also use the standard library:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
resHTML = ET.Element('html',attrib={'lang':'en'})
body = ET.SubElement(resHTML,'body')
p1 = ET.SubElement(body,'p')
span1 = ET.SubElement(p1,'span', attrib={'id': 'anIDA'})
span1.text = "mytext"

with open("HTMLtest.html","wb") as o:
    o.write(b"<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
    o.write(ET.tostring(resHTML))

# cleanest  way using Beautiful Soup
import bs4
with open("HTMLtest.html","w") as o:
    o.write(bs4.BeautifulSoup(ET.tostring(resHTML), "html").prettify())
```