# reading href in a loop from python code

Tags: python, html, model-view-controller

I have a piece of html code that look like this:

```
<div class="menu-item"> 
      <a class="menu-link" href="/dashboard/apple"> C-apple</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item"> 
      <a class="menu-link" href="/dashboard/bench"> C-bench</a>
</div>
```

but i wanna read the `href="/dashboard/{name}"> {title} </a>` from a python list and display it using a for loop or while loop instead of hard coding, how can i do that?
thanks

Comment: Try loading it with beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

Here is an Example

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    a = 0
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            self.a = 1
            print 'name:', dict(attrs)['href'].split('/')[-1]
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.a == 1:
            print 'title:', data
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.a = 0

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('''
<div class="menu-item"> 
      <a class="menu-link" href="/dashboard/apple"> C-apple</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item"> 
      <a class="menu-link" href="/dashboard/bench"> C-bench</a>
</div>
''')
```

And you run it you will get the output

```
name: apple
title:  C-apple
name: bench
title:  C-bench
```

Comment: i am actually looking to feed those variables as a tuple to html from a python file,
i was actually looking some thing like

`<div class="menu-item">
    {% for name, project in dashboard_data %}
 <ul>
     <li><a href="/dashboard/" + {project}>{name}</a></li>
 </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</div>`

Comment: Maybe you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301163/creating-html-in-python

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for the help and this solved my problem

```
{%for name, title in tuples:%}
   <div class="menu-item">
      <a class="menu-link" href="/dashboard/{{title}}">{{name}}</a>
   </div>
{%endfor%}
```