# How to create HTML frontend for python

Tags: python

I would like to write a simple python application, that generates a HTML "website" as frontend. It is not meant to be hosted online or to consist of multiple pages. The user will simply open the frontend in a browser.

There should be only one `index.html` file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-styles.css">
    ...
</head>

<body>
    {python_body_var}
</body>
```

Where `python_body_var` is an object (or string-representation) of the python-internal state.

Is there a simple way to implement this? Could I easily register event handlers for buttons etc.?

The important thing about this is, that any user interaction (clicking elements, inserting text, ...) should be noticed in the backend. And the frontend should actively respond to certain changes in the backend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301163/creating-html-in-python

Comment: @Corbie you could add a script tag into your page and then use javascript inside the script tag to add event handlers.

Comment: Javascript cannot directly communicate with python. All the important stuff should happen in the backend. E.g. if the user clicks a button, the python backend shall create an image and display it in a (new) `img` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your python script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index(): 
    my_string = "hello world"
    return render_template("index.html", body=my_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And in a folder called templates have an html document called `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<body>
    <p>{{body}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

run the python script and go to `http://localhost:5000/` in your browser and you will see it. your folder structure will look like this

```
main.py
templates
|____index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

https://anvil.works/ is a dedicated platform where you can build the prototype easily only with python.

Comment: This is nice for hobby projects and very large public projects, where the costs are neglectable. For on-site projects this does not work without an expensive enterprise license.