# How to create HTML table using Python w/o using any packages or library?

Tags: python, html-table

I have been searching for how to get a good HTML table from Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating HTML in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301163/creating-html-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I'm aware of in the standard library is using an ElementTree from the xml package, like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

rows = ['A', 'B', 'C']
cols = ['1', '2', '3']
table = ElementTree.Element("table")
for row_name in rows:
    row = ElementTree.SubElement(table, 'tr')
    for col_name in cols:
        ElementTree.SubElement(row, 'td').text = row_name + col_name
ElementTree.dump(table)
```

The output will be this:
`<table><tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr><tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr><tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr></table>`
which is a standard HTML table. You can modify it in all the expected ways with an ElementTree, ie adding attributes, table headers, etc.

Edit: in response to the question title changing, if you wanted to do this without using any imports you could use code like this:

```
rows = ['A', 'B', 'C']
cols = ['1', '2', '3']

table = '<table>'
for row in rows:
    table += '<tr>'
    for col in cols:
        table += f'<td>{row + col}</td>'
    table += '</tr>'
table += '</table>'
```

to get the same result manually.

Answer (score -2):

I would say this will probably be the easiest way to create simple html table using python for new comer.

```
html = f"""<table border='1' style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{header_name_1}</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{header_name_2}</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{header_name_3}</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{header_name_4}</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{header_name_5}</th>
                </tr>
            """
for data in datas:
        html += f"""<tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{data_name_1}</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{data_name_2}</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{data_name_3}</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{data_name_4}</td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">{data_name_5}</td>
                    </tr>
                """
    
html = html + "</table>"
```